# Git credential store doesn't work on Centos6

Tags: git, gitlab, credentials, centos6

On my server Centos6 the command "git config --global credential.helper store", not have any effect.
The variable correctly set, indeed running "git config --global credential.helper" i receive "store", and I have no local configuration.

But the password is prompted every time a run a pull or a push.

Comment: How is gitlab an issue in this question?  What makes you think anything is "provocated by gitlab installation"?

Comment: Agreed. This is a client-side issue and has nothing to do with GitLab.

Answer (score 0):

The information on the official Git site may be helpful. It describes some different credential helper options including `cache` and `store`. You may need to define a path for the `store` helper to keep the credentials it saves. For example, `git config --global credential.helper 'store --file ~/.my-credentials'`

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Credential-Storage